# Append in a list [Python]

Tags: python, list, append, attributeerror

could someone please explain to me why I have this error message :

line 27, in 
liste_de_courses.append(item_add)

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append**

Thank you in advance for your help

```
import os
import json

dossier_courant = os.path.dirname(__file__)

dossier = os.path.join (dossier_courant, "liste.json")

if os.path.exists(dossier):
    with open (dossier, "r") as f:
        liste_de_courses = json.load(f)
else:
    liste_de_courses = []

affichage = """
\t1: Add a item
\t2: Delete a item
\t3: Show a item
\t4: Empty a item
\t5: Over
"""
choix_utilisateur = "0"
while choix_utilisateur != "5":

    choix_utilisateur = input (affichage)
    if choix_utilisateur == "1":
        item_add = input ("What would you like to add ? ")
        liste_de_courses.append(item_add)
    elif choix_utilisateur == "2":
        item_delete = input ("What item do you wish to remove ? ")
        if item_delete in liste_de_courses:
            liste_de_courses.remove(item_delete)
print ("Bye")
```

Comment: json.load() method (without “s” in “load”) used to read JSON encoded data from a file and convert it into Python dictionary.  You are trying to append as though it is a list.

Comment: @JoeFerndz: It needn't be a Python `dict`; legal JSON includes simple double-quoted strings, or (square-)bracketed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Add `print(type(liste_de_courses))` after this.

```py
with open (dossier, "r") as f:
    liste_de_courses = json.load(f)
```

What is the type of `liste_de_courses`?

Comment: it's a type << list >>
I found the problem, it's my JSON file, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is storing a JSON string (Python `str`), not a JSON array (Python `list`). You need to fix your input file.

Comment: Thank you :) I understood well @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 0):

The liste_de_courses is not a list but it is a string.
I don't know anything about json but check that json.load(f) returns what and of which type.

Comment: If it helped you mark this answer a accepted please.